# How to change a user name in an expired trial org?

Tags: user, duplicate-management

Suppose you want to add someone as a user to an org and you get the "Duplicate Username" error? And the person in question remembers that (s)he has in fact used that username in a trial org, which has expired by now. And that company and technical policies require that you must use that particular username? (E.g. when using SSO or user provisioning from Active Directory).

According to [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000krseAAA) and [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-do-I-receive-an-error-message-Duplicate-Username-1327109140698&language=en_US) you're in trouble. You are not able to fix it, the user is not able to fix it and Salesforce will not fix it.

So now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Salesforce Support can help you. I created a Case and they fixed it. They sent a mail to the concerned user, asking him for permission to change the username in the expired trial org. After the permission was given, Salesforce changed the username (it takes a while before that change has propagated) and problem solved!

Edit: I also found [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004866&language=en_US) that states "In the event that the administrator is unable to access the old organization, they can reach out to Salesforce support to free up the usernames. This will apply for orgs that has expired or locked". This contradicts the other help page (from the question) that claims that Salesforce will not do this.